# Java - assertEquals & assertTrue - Test failed with exception [null] in JUnit but passes in test class

Tags: java, exception, junit, null, assert

I have both a standard test class with a main method and a JUnit class which I am using to base my tests while writing a contact directory via Test Driven Development. I need to make use of methods such as assertEquals & assertTrue. As I have never used them before, I wrote a simple test in my standard test class and they return True when expected and throw an exception when expected.

I then moved into my JUnit test class, write the same test that passed in the standard test class and run the JUnit test class. The test fails with the following error:

```
Test[Method Name] failed with exception [null]
```

The exact code I used is along these lines:

```
assertEquals("NameImExpectingToFind",obj.searchMethod("nameImSearchingFor").get(0).getName());
```

I've been stuck on this problem for hours. Just makes no sense that it will pass in a standard test class but not in a JUnit test class.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
Test class:
    AddressBook main = new AddressBook();
    Entry Will = new Entry("Will", "Blah",
            "Blah, blah, blah", "TF4 3HS", "077774451",
            "01/02/93");
    Entry Ben = new Entry("Ben", "Blah",
            "Blah, blah, blah", "TF4 3HS", "077774451",
            "01/02/93");
    main.addEntry(Will);
    main.addEntry(Ben);
    //assertEquals("Ben",main.cSearchFirst("Ben").get(0).getfName());
    System.out.println("Ben" == main.cSearchFirst("Ben").get(0).getfName());
```

Returns True.

```
JUnit Test class:
    AddressBook main = new AddressBook();
    Entry Will = new Entry("Will", "Blah",
            "Blah, blah, blah", "TF4 3HS", "077774451",
            "01/02/93");
    Entry Ben = new Entry("Ben", "Blah",
            "Blah, blah, blah", "TF4 3HS", "077774451",
            "01/02/93");
    main.addEntry(Will);
    main.addEntry(Ben);
    assertEquals("Ben",main.cSearchFirst("Ben").get(0).getfName());
    //System.out.println("Ben" == main.cSearchFirst("Ben").get(0).getfName());
```

Returns Test[Method Name] failed with exception [null].

Comment: You need to show us more of the code (the whole test method, in both classes).

Comment: Just added some more. Hope that helps.

Comment: Split main.cSearchFirst("Ben").get(0).getfName() into individual intermediary variables to see which level is null if you don't know how to debug this as a single expression. There's nothing JUnit-specific here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you got a null pointer, before your test do

```
 List<Entry> entries = main.cSearchFirst("Ben");//check for null here, and size
 Entry e = entries.get(0); //again check null here, examine properties in debugger
 String s = e.getfName();
```

Slap a debugger on there and walk through seeing where null is being thrown.

edit: I'd also recommend doing a checks for nulls around there if you are expecting null, else try/catch null exceptions and fail the test.

Comment: I just added some more code if that helps aid your suspicions?

Comment: That was an accident. Updated to reflect true code. Thanks for the help so far though. Any more would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ben".equals(testStuff) Returns True in the test class also.

Comment: I have updated the code again to change it to main. All "friends" should have read "main".

Comment: @user2962713 okay, have you tried my previous changes? Separating "main.cSearchFirst("Ben").get(0).getfName()" into separate steps and walking through where that could be null?

Comment: Working on it now. No luck so far.

Comment: @user2962713 Another alternative is to do a try/catch for nulls around the assertEquals and print the stack trace. Might be something broken with JUnit.

Comment: @user2962713 You accepted this answer without indicating what was wrong with your code, making it completely useless for anyone who found this question in future.